# Android Wear API JavaDoc in Android Studio not providing enough documentation

Tags: android-studio, javadoc, wear-os

When I press F1 on a mac for onCreate() I get documentation. 
It seems for Android Wear API it's not fully documented i.e. onExitAmbient()
It would help if it was more documented, as it is now you have to refer to the external link here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/activity/WearableActivity.html

But how can I integrate it in Studio the best way?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/package-summary is for Google Play Services, and not for the wearable support library that contains ambient support. The wearable support library is here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/package-summary.html

Comment: When I did Fn-F1 on onExitAmbient() I received this output: com.example.android.wearable.wear.alwayson.MainActivity
public void onExitAmbient()
Prepares UI for Active view (non-Ambient).
Overrides:
onExitAmbient in class WearableActivity

Comment: Which Android Studio version are you using?

Comment: Sorry what I meant was why is there no good description? The link you provided says for example: Called when an activity should exit ambient mode. And when you look on for example OnCreate in Activity it explains it in more detail. To me it's seems the Wear API is not documented enough in JavaDoc. Corrected the link above.

Comment: And further down in the external doc: Called when an activity should exit ambient mode. This event is sent while an activity is running (after onResume, before onPause).
Derived classes must call through to the super class's implementation of this method. If they do not, an exception will be thrown. - Should this not be in the JavaDoc? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Let me look into this for you.